# Help Creating a Component with Simple Backend

Tags: component, administrator

I am new to Joomla development and am trying to make a, in my mind at least, very simple component, but I can't seem to find the right tutorials online.  I've already looked at the Joomla! Docs for creating a component, but it isn't explained very well if at all.  I want to create a component which has only a backend with two text boxes and a submit button, that's it.  I don't want any lists, toolbars, or anything else, just two textfields and a button. If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Check these: [**How do you make a module**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-do-you-make-a-new-module/661#661) and [**Joomla Development Tutorials**](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/joomla-3-x-extension-development-tutorial-for-a-beginner-developer)

Comment: Have a look around for some component generators ;)

Comment: Are you sure you need a component for two text boxes and a submit button? You can do module in the backend too.

Answer (score 2):

I use this:  http://www.component-creator.com/en/

Assembling all the files and the component setup is tedious and time consuming.  I'm sure there is a very relevant place to understand the build process from scratch but the mentioned creator assembles the component to about a 90% completion.

Here's the video I used to learn how to get started with Component Creator:  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OXkZTxN3r98

It's free to use for one database table and small monthly fee to build with unlimited tables.  I start all my components with this resource

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I had already looked at Component Creator, unfortunately, I do not need a table of any kind in this component, so from that regard it is useless to me, but it is good for compiling the necessary files

Comment: If you don't need to store the data via table, are you using the fields and submit to generate an outbound email?  What's the functionality?  You can always consider a module or plugin which are easier to assemble than components.

Comment: Yes, it will ultimately end in an email being sent out to different users, I'll look into modules