# Are there Joomla Website (not content!): Application lifecycle management best practices?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development

Good Morning

As a professional developer I use professional tools like Git to manage e.g. source files on the Server and other tools to manage Application-Settings, in this context Joomla-Website settings which are saved in the Database (and not content).

Are there any best practices for

- manage source file versions during development
- deploy
- and managing configuration changes

for Joomla Websites?

Thanks a lot for any help!
kind regards,
Thomas

Comment: Hello Tom, I am still not very clear on what exactly you are asking... are any of the answers here helpful? http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/12143/what-tools-can-i-use-to-help-assist-me-with-joomla-development

Answer (score 1):

The webhosting company SiteGround (siteground.com) has a Joomla-specific Git that works pretty well along with a "Staging" tool that allows you to create working copies of the site, make changes, then push the site live. (I use Siteground but have no other connection to them.) - Greg

Comment: Hi Greg, thank you very much for this Link!, it sounds great and we will have a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Some useful resources:

- [Joomla! Coding Standards Manual.](http://joomla.github.io/coding-standards/)
- [Development Best Practices.](https://docs.joomla.org/Development_Best_Practices)
- [Secure Coding Guidelines.](https://docs.joomla.org/Secure_coding_guidelines)
- [Securing Joomla! Extensions.](https://docs.joomla.org/Securing_Joomla_extensions)
- [Best Practices at Testing.](https://docs.joomla.org/Testing_Joomla_Extensions_with_Codeception#Best_Practices_at_Testing)
- [Unit Testing Best Practices.](https://docs.joomla.org/Unit_Testing_Best_Practices)

Comment: Thank you very much, AlexVega, for taking time to answer my question!, unfortunately my question was not precise enough: the Development itself is no problem - but it looks like Joomla has no concept to get deployed from a Repository (Git, TFS, ...) and there is probably no available concept to manage Joomla configuration changes (the configuration which is stored in the Database)