# Load joomla to a computer

Tags: user

Can I download joomla.org and templates to my computer to build my web site on the computer prior to loading it to my server?
Thanks

Comment: A set of tools the community has provided: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/12143/168

Answer (score 1):

**Local Environment**

Joomla runs best on Apache web server with MySQL and PHP.

The Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP (LAMP) stack can be enabled on your Linux operating system and there are equivalent options for Windows and Mac users such as [WAMP](https://www.virtualbox.org) and [MAMP](https://github.com/joomlatools/joomlatools-vagrant).

It may be easier to install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) with [Joomlatools Vagrant](https://github.com/joomlatools/joomlatools-vagrant) or [Joomla 3 Turnkey Linux](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/joomla3) or similar. These tools are all free and available for Linux, Windows and Mac host operating systems.

**Moving a Joomla Website**

The easiest way to move a website from the web to your local machine or vice versa is to use free or paid version of Akeeba Backup to backup the website, FTP the file to the destination, and then use Akeeba Kickstart to restore the website to the destination.