# How to create a Joomla module and be able to install it?

Tags: module, installation

I've read all the official Joomla documentation and videos available to learn how to make a basic module, however, when I finish making a module, I can't manage to install it in my Joomla project.

I am receiving the following error

> It was not possible find the installation package.

Can anybody help me?

The server I use is Apache and the module files are these https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KYjSUCzorrfm54p2JNVPqh7FlYKyyjnG/view?usp=sharing
As simple as possible.

Comment: Can you provide more detail in your question like the file structure of your Module and how you have packaged the module to an installer file. In simple terms you need to have a modulename.xml file that describes how to install it and the related code files and compress them into a .zip or .tar file. The messages suggest it can't find the modulename.xml file

Comment: This might be helpful as well https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/655/how-to-develop-a-joomla-module

Comment: @Irata , I did exactly as you described and, searching a little more, I saw that the error is really in the .xml file, as you said. Then, when I tried to install again, Joomla specified the message: "The manifest file could not be detected"
Researching some more, people who had the same problem solved it by giving written permission, but I'm not sure how to do it and if it would solve my problem.
I'll put some information here and the module I'm trying to install: I use Apache and the module files are the ones I put in the post, after editing it.

Comment: The module files you have uploaded are installable without any error on my localhost. Could it be that the file permissions on your server are wrong? What about the tmp path?  Is it set correctly and to an existing folder?

Comment: @FFrewin Did you install the module without issue using the RAR format it was provided in or did you convert it to a .zip format?

Comment: @Irata - I actually unRARed the file and placed the module in the modules directory and tried the discover installation. Then I deleted from db, zipped the previously unRARed  files and installed again with zip upload. That's what I tried. Never went to try the rar install.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the same message about not being able to find the install file so I compressed your module as a .zip and it installed fine.

It is likely that your hosting environment is not able to handle the .RAR format.

Terry

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who helped me. I managed to solve the problem.
After reading the comments, I realized the mistake I was making. The file has to be specifically .zip, but I thought that any compressed file he would be able to interpret, but not. This may be due to my server, but I'm not sure. Sorry for my stupidity. kjsksjksjk

Thank you all for your help again: Irata and FFrewin.

Comment: The webserver needs to be able to extract archives. The Joomla requirements page https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements mentions that you need the mod_zlib Apache module. That's used for extracting .zip archives. Joomla uses .zip archives. However Joomla's update packages are also available in .tar.bz2 and .tar.gz format but I have not seen any non-core extension using those formats.

Comment: I've just updated Joomla's documentation about using the .zip format: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module